# What makes a variable 'not appear free' in a lambda expression

Tags: haskell, lambda

Page 11 in [Philip Wadler's Monads for functional programming](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/marktoberdorf/baastad.pdf) states:

> The operations of a monad satisfy three laws.
>
> ...
>
> *Associative*. Compute `m`, bind the result to `a`, compute `n`, bind the result to `b`, compute `o`. The order of parentheses in such a computation is irrelevant.
>
> ```
> m ★ (λa. n ★ λb. o) = (m ★ λa. n) ★ λb. o.
> ```
>
> The scope of the variable *a* includes *o* on the left but excludes *o* on the right, so this law is valid only when *a* does not appear free in *o*.

What makes a variable 'not appear free' in this context?

Comment: Every term has a set of [free variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables). A variable does not appear free in a term if the the variable is not a member of the set of free variables of the term.

Answer (score 5):

`a` does not appear free in `o` if (and only if) all occurrences of `a` in `o` are within a lambda that binds `a`.

So for example if `o = \a. a` or `o = x` (`a` does not appear at all), `a` does not appear free in `o`, but if `o = a` or `o = \b. a b`, `a` does appear free.